# is it possible to connect to connect to an "IPSec" or "IPSec Xauth PSK" VPN with windows 10

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn

I have a FritzBox 7490 router that offers an VPN option using just "IPSec" or "IPSec Xauth PSK", in Android or iOs it is easy to configure a VPN connection with that data (share key, password and user) but on windows 10 that option it is not available there in the VPN menu.

I have test it with an really old [2013 VPN Software](https://www.shrew.net/download/vpn) and it works, but I is not being maintained, is there a way to set a VPN connection directly on windows using "IPSec" or "IPSec Xauth PSK"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to make a VPN based on IPSec – it took a while for this way of using IPSec to become standardized. Windows 10 has a built-in IKEv2 EAP (new standard) client and an IKEv1 PSK + L2TP (Microsoft style) client, but it *does not* have an IKEv1 Xauth (Cisco-style) client for the method that FritzBox uses.

It *might* be possible to configure Windows as a peer for FritzBox's IKEv1 PSK without Xauth, but it won't have the VPN-style automatic setup and it would be completely static (i.e. permanently on). Also it's a headache.